# Suggestions for building and managing complex functions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Far too often, I've got a formula that wraps functions inside of functions inside of functions, and when some new condition requires that I wrap another function around it, I often find myself completely losing track of which parentheses go where, which function applies to which set of parameters and usually find myself debugging a statement for a half hour after my modification produces unexpected results.

What I've BEEN doing is to cut the function into its individual parts in a column...each row representing a single function, and when I'm satisfied that end result is what it needs to be, I copy each piece back into it's respective spot in the preceding cell until I have a completed, and hopefully working, function.

CONSIDER:

```
         =IF((ISERROR((VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A9,1,0))),(IF((D2=(VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A$9,1,0))),0,D2)),E2)
0        =IF((ISERROR((VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A9,1,0))),L17,E2)
TRUE     =ISERROR((VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A9,1,0))
0        =IF((D2=L18),0,D2)
the      =VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A$9,1,0)
```

It'd be great to be able to document inline or have something similar to a VBA popup ion which to edit formulae, but since that *doesn't* exist, I'd be interested to know what other techniques for effectively building complex functions you've found helpful. Thoughts?

Comment: This is a question to superuser.com - I marked it to transfer. As soon as done - I'll provide you with the hints I use on my own and for stuff training in my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I split formulas over multiple columns - each column then contains a part of the formula. I never stuck them into a single cell - while "cleaner" they are impossible to debug.
If the columns are to much, I build a "admin" sheet, which can be hidden.

I dislike the excel formula editor in general - while I really like the power of the formulas, the editor is a pain to use.